# How to create a Curtain Effect with SVG Paths?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm inspired by the page loading curtain effect seen here: [https://www.epicurrence.com](https://www.epicurrence.com/)

Here's a screen recording:

[image]

I'd love to learn how to do something similar. Can anyone help me understand how to approach this problem? Are their libraries people use for this or is it all custom? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: one of the easiest ways to get animated SVG effects is https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web ... to use it you create your animation in Adobe Aftereffects then export using their AE Plugin called Bodymovin. You then include a small amount of JS to render the animated SVG in the dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly trivial to reproduce with SVG.

All we do is wait for a click, then animate between three path shapes:

1. A rectangle, with a semicircular bottom that is off the page
2. A rectangle, with a semicircular bottom that is near the top of the page
3. A rectangle, with zero height, at the top of the page.

And when the animation is over, we hide the SVG to show the page behind it.

Demo *(click the black part to start the animation)*

```js
var curtain = document.getElementById("curtain");

curtain.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  // Call beginElement() on the <animate> element to start the animation running
  document.getElementById("curtainAnimate").beginElement();
});
```

```css
/* Make the SVG fill the screen */
svg {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test page</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, an possit conceptam per. Et lorem qualisque deterruisset mei. Et doctus dissentias vim. Sit inciderint eloquentiam eu, vel diceret veritus patrioque eu, per in congue causae salutatus.</p>

<p>Posse iriure ut nam, tempor veritus vis ex. Ex viris legendos salutatus eos, eam primis meliore signiferumque an. Graeci civibus similique ius ad. Diam ponderum laboramus per ex, autem denique probatus mei in. Vel in saepe mucius tamquam, pri ex iusto graeco comprehensam. Usu deserunt mediocrem et. Quo iisque ullamcorper cu.</p>

<p>Ex vis vero signiferumque, eum quem lobortis an. Eu vidisse erroribus intellegam sed, velit vituperata in vis. Ad omnis mundi dicam eam, ut mea malorum expetendis voluptatum, mea agam option no. Ei pro vero mediocrem. Nam ea velit facete, suas graeci omnesque cum et. At vix invidunt neglegentur, porro ullum numquam id vim.</p>

<p>Sale fabulas sed no, at mel ullum facilis omittantur. In nam zril vitae graece, vis id facete tamquam. Cu discere numquam percipitur mea. Duo nominati evertitur ex, meis impedit forensibus mei ad.</p>

<p>Veniam mucius at mei. Vel ad aliquip accusamus posidonium, his aperiri nonumes cu. Ei duo deleniti repudiare adipiscing, agam impedit per ut. No dicat utinam homero ius, ut ius impedit posidonium reprehendunt.</p>

<svg id="curtain" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path fill="#333" d="M 100,0 L 0,0 L 0,130 c 0,-17, 23,-30, 50,-30 c 27,0, 50,13, 50,30 Z">
    <animate id="curtainAnimate" attributeName="d"
             begin="indefinite" dur="1s" fill="freeze"
             keyTimes="0; 0.7; 1"
             values="M 100,0 L 0,0 L 0,130 c 0,-17, 23,-30, 50,-30 c 27,0, 50,13, 50,30 Z;
                     M 100,0 L 0,0 L 0,50  c 0,-17, 23,-30, 50,-30 c 27,0, 50,13, 50,30 Z;
                     M 100,0 L 0,0 L 0,0   c 0,0, 50,0, 50,0       c 0,0, 50,0, 50,0 Z"/>
  </path>
  <!-- Hides the SVG when the path animation ends -->
  <set begin="curtainAnimate.end" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="display" to="none"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: amazing. thank you so much for the pointer in the right direction

Comment: How are you coming up with the values  in the code? Is there an app you're using?

Comment: I'm eager to learn how you came up with these path values. Where does one even start?

Comment: You could use an app, but these ones were so simple that I just did them manually. The path format is very simple, and quite easy to understand. Try [reading the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-PathData) and experimenting